Calculate weighted average using Pandas groupby and deal with NaN
I'm trying to calculate the weighted average using groupby. However, I'm dealing with empty value in my dataframe.
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'group': ['a', 'a', 'a', 'a'],
    'x': [10, 20, np.nan, 20],
    'weight_x': [10, 15, np.nan, 25],
    'y': [25, 35, 45, np.nan],
    'weight_y': [10, 20, 10, np.nan]
})

This is my groupby function:
summary = (
    df
    .groupby(['group'])
    .apply(
        lambda x: pd.Series([
            np.average(x['x'], weights=x['weight_x']),
            np.average(x['y'], weights=x['weight_y'])
        ], index=['wt_avg_x', 'wt_avg_y'])
    )
    .reset_index()
)

This one gives the following output:
  group  wt_avg_x  wt_avg_y
0     a       NaN       NaN

However, expected output should be the following:
  group  wt_avg_x  wt_avg_y
0     a      20.5        35

I've tried this solution:
summary = (
    df.dropna(subset=['x', 'y', 'weight_x', 'weight_y'])
    .groupby(['group'])
    .apply(
        lambda x: pd.Series([
            np.average(x['x'], weights=x['weight_x']),
            np.average(x['y'], weights=x['weight_y'])
        ], index=['wt_avg_x', 'wt_avg_y'])
    )
    .reset_index()
)

But dropna drops the whole line. How could I ignore nan values only in the np.average function?

How do you get 20.5? shouldn't that be 18?

Why is wt_avg_x 20.5? If I do np.average([10, 20, 20], weights=[10, 15, 25]), I get 18.0. That's effectively what you want, isn't it?

You could also use the following:
def nan_average(x, cols = ['x', 'y']):
    vals = x[cols]
    weights = x[[f'weight_{c}' for c in cols]].to_numpy()
    return np.sum(vals*weights,0)/weights.sum(0,where=~np.isnan(vals.to_numpy()))

df.groupby('group').apply(nan_average).reset_index()
  group     x     y
0     a  18.0  35.0


Another way:
a = df.rename(columns = {'x':'val_x', 'y':'val_y'}).reset_index()

(pd.wide_to_long(a, ['val','weight'], ['index', 'group'], '', '_', '\\w+')
    .groupby(level=[1,2]).apply(lambda x: np.nansum(x.val * x.weight)/
            x.weight.to_numpy().sum(where=~np.isnan(x.val.to_numpy())))
    .unstack().reset_index())

  group     x     y
0     a  18.0  35.0


SOLUTION 1
A possible solution, whose steps are:

First, it replaces all NaN values in df with zeros using fillna(0).

Then, it groups the df by the group column using groupby with as_index=False to keep group as a column in the result.

Within the aggregation function agg, a dictionary comprehension iterates over the columns x and y.

For each column, it computes the weighted sum by multiplying the column values by their corresponding weights (weight_x or weight_y), summing the products, and dividing by the sum of the weights.


out = df.fillna(0)

out.groupby('group', as_index=False).agg({
    key: (lambda g, k=key: (g.mul(out.loc[g.index, f'weight_{k}'])).sum() 
          / out.loc[g.index, f'weight_{k}'].sum())
    for key in ['x', 'y']
})


SOLUTION 2
Another possible solution, whose steps are:

First, it uses groupby to group the df by the group column.

Within a lambda function, a dictionary comprehension iterates over the keys x and y, performing the following steps for each:

Drops missing values from the target column using dropna.
Multiplies the non-missing values by the corresponding weights, also with missing values dropped.
Sums the weighted values and divides by the sum of the weights to calculate the weighted average.


The results are returned as a Series for each group.


df.groupby('group', as_index=False).apply(
    lambda g: pd.Series({
        'wt_avg_' + key: g[key].dropna().mul(g[f'weight_{key}'].dropna()).sum() / 
            g[f'weight_{key}'].dropna().sum()
        for key in ['x', 'y']
    }), include_groups=False
).reset_index(drop=True)


Output:
  group  wt_avg_x  wt_avg_y
0     a      18.0      35.0


To the downvoter: Could you please explain what justify your downvote, so that I can improve or even remove my answer?

The issues is due to the NaNs in your data, this will force the average to be NaN.
One option could be to use masked numpy arrays for numpy.average to correctly perform the computations:
def f(g, cols=['x', 'y']):
    # infer weight columns from value columns
    # you could also use hardcoded names or a parameter
    w_cols = [f'weight_{c}' for c in cols]
    # mask values
    v = np.ma.MaskedArray(g[cols], mask=g[cols].isna())
    # mask weigths
    w = np.ma.MaskedArray(g[w_cols], mask=g[w_cols].isna())
    # compute the weighted average per column
    return pd.Series(np.average(v, weights=w, axis=0), index=cols)
    
summary = (
    df
    .groupby(['group'])
    .apply(f)
    .reset_index()
)

Shorter (but probably less efficient) approach using a mask to only select the non-NA data:
def f(g, cols=['x', 'y']):
    return pd.Series([np.average(g.loc[(m:=g[c].notna()), c],
                                 weights=g.loc[m, f'weight_{c}'],
                                 axis=0)
                      for c in cols], index=cols)
    
summary = (
    df
    .groupby(['group'])
    .apply(f)
    .reset_index()
)

Output:
  group     x     y
0     a  18.0  35.0


Any issue with the answer?
